# How to duplicate synchronized data extension and put in data extensions folder

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, duplicate-management

I need to essentially mimic a synchronized data extension but in the data extensions folder.  I think what I need to do is duplicate the synched data extension into the DE folder, populate it from a query in an automation that runs at a set interval.

My problem; in regular (non-synched) data extensions, I can just duplicate the data extension from the menu and get all fields in my new data extension. This doesn't seem possible in the menu of the synchronized data extension.  Is there a way to copy all the fields in the synched data extension to a new data extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out an answer to this one in case anyone needs it.  I queried the synchronized data extension for the fields I was looking for (interactions > query).  I chose the data extensions folder as my target.  I created an empty data extension with all the fields I was querying in the data extension folder.  I then set up an automation to run the query which output the results into my new data extension.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be optimal but you can use SOAP API to describe the synchronized data extension to get all its fields and then use them back to create the non-synch version

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This is a little beyond my skill set at this point.  I was hoping for a simpler way to do this, but it sounds like it might not be possible.